# Python package is donwloaded but not saved

Tags: python, artifactory, torch

I am trying to d/l "torch" package via Artifactory. It seems that the files are d/l well and are install in my python but from some reason they do not seems to be save in Artifactory. If afterwards I am exporting my repository, the export folder is very small (about 250K) while the d/l files are about 200M.

Also, when I search "torch" in Artifactory, I can see an HTML file name torch but not what i used to once see which is the torch whl file with its version.

It seems that when d/l all other package they do save in Artifactory. I just can't understand why this package is different.

D/l comamnd is:
 `pip3 install torch==1.8.1+cu111 torchvision==0.9.1+cu111 torchaudio===0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

Answer (score 1):

Pip uses the url in your command directly, hence it is not talking to Artifactory to get these packages and thus Artifactory cannot cache them.

Resolved issue # 24541 requested that Artifactory add support for the PyTorch PyPI repo:
https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-24541

The release notes indicate that the PyTorch repo was first supported in Artifactory version 7.28.9, released November 19, 2021:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Release+Notes

You would need to add the remote repository configuration on your Artifactory server, though I don't have the exact steps for that. You would also need to remove the download.pytorch.org url from your pip3 install command and instead configure pip to resolve packages using only Artifactory. I presume you would want pip configured to use a virtual repo on your Artifactory server, which is configured to reference two remote repos: both the normal PyPI repo and this PyTorch repo.